# Convert list items to list if not list in python

Tags: python, list

There is a list like that

```
mylist = [[1,2,3], 7, [4,5,6], [7,8,9],5]
```

As you notice, it is a list of nested lists and that is OK .. But there are some items in the mylist which are not considered a list. How can I convert those to nested lists too
I mean the output should be like that

```
mylist = [[1,2,3], [7], [4,5,6], [7,8,9],[5]]
```

Comment: If list is`[7, 5]`, what's the expected output? `[[7], [5]]` or `[[7, 5]]`?

Comment: `[[7], [5]]` is the expected and will be inside the main list as the final output.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3], 7, [4,5,6], [7,8,9],5]

mylist = [item if isinstance(item, list) else [item] for item in mylist]
print(mylist)
# [[1, 2, 3], [7], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [5]]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```py
>>> mylist = [[1,2,3], 7, [4,5,6], [7,8,9],5]
>>> mylist = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in mylist]
>>> mylist
[[1, 2, 3], [7], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [5]]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The same as @Thierry Lathuille